# Format int as 000000_0000

Tags: python, python-2.7

In ironpython (Python 2.7) can I format an int to output a string like this:

```
1     --> 000000_0001
10000 --> 000001_0000
```

The `"{}".format` syntax doesn't seem to support custom chars.

This is what I tried for now:

```
def format(self, num):
    pre = int(num * 0.0001)
    tail = int(num - (pre*1/0.0001))

    return "{}_{}".format("{0:06d}".format(pre), "{0:04d}".format(tail))
```

But I was hoping there was a cleaner way. In `C#` it would have been:

```
num.ToString("000000_0000")
```

edit: I ended up with a variant of Parsa

```
def format(num):
    num = str(num).zfill(10)
    return "{}_{}".format(num[0:6], num[6:10])
```

Comment: Did you try creating the version of the string without underscores first, then using code to insert underscores in the appropriate places?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I added my take on it. Forgot about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def print_with_format(i):
    print("{0}_{1}".format(str(i).zfill(8)[0:4], str(i).zfill(8)[4:8]))

print_with_format(18965)
```

[image]

Comment: Note that this calls twice to both `str` and to `zfill`. Might be better to pre-calculate

Comment: I ended up with a variant of yours

Comment: Yes it calls them twice but it's a one line code with 1 less varible

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```py
total_length = 8
half_length = total_length / 2

num = 10000

zfilled_num = str(num).zfill(total_length)
underscored = zfilled_num[:half_length] + "_" + zfilled_num[half_length:]

print underscored
# 0001_0000
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM9LNLMrP@/@/JL8kMSc@JzUvvSRDwVbBgisjMScNwUeR1lcw4uLKK80FihsaAAEXV1VaZk5Oako8RLC4pEgDyNLUAwtrIOvV5CrNS0ktKk7OL0pNASpF0hhthWRlrIK2glK8EpBEVoGkwCqWi6ugKDOvRAPJQM3//wE)

Comment: There is nothin like c# equivalent, num.ToString("000000_0000")?

Comment: @Anders No, not that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 1):

As [@Karl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/523612/karl-knechtel) suggested create a padded string first and then insert the `_`.

Here's how:

```
def halve_it(n):
    p = '{:010d}'.format(n)
    return '{}_{}'.format(p[:6], p[6:])

print halve_it(12345)
```

Output:

```
>>> def halve_it(n):
...     p = '{:010d}'.format(n)
...     return '{}_{}'.format(p[:6], p[6:])
...
>>> print halve_it(10000)
000001_0000
>>> >>> print halve_it(12345)
000001_2345
>>> print halve_it(1)
000000_0001
>>> print halve_it(9876543)
000987_6543
```